# Как можно предсказать следующее значение числового ряда?

Tags: алгоритм

Если весь ряд состоит только из чисел 1, 2, 3, то как определить какое будет следующее число?

---

**Из комментариев:**
Ряд состоит исключительно из чисел 1, 2, 3 в произвольном порядке.
Например, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2...

Добрый вечер всем. Спасибо за огромное количество ответов, буду читать и знакомиться с методами. Вопрос еще и в том можно ли загнать последовательность в матлаб или стаистику или реализовать в экселе. Выборка на сегодня составляет 1333 при этом, первые 75 не известны (опытным путем выяснил что они есть может это тоже важно), а известны последующие 1258. Возможны следующие варианты их расположения тройками 111,222,333
311,131,113,331,133,313,322,232,223,332,233,323,211,121,112,221,122,212,132,123,231,213,312,321 , то есть как бы 27 вариантов. К воскр перепишу всю выборку как пример и покажу ее

Comment: Правильно я вас понял, что ряд состоит исключительно из чисел 1, 2, 3 в произвольном порядке? Например 1,2,3,2,3,1,2...

Comment: Да совершенно верно, вы правильно поняли, если можите подскажите где про это можно почитать или посмотреть как это делается

Comment: Может быть использовать цепи Маркова https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%8C_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0.

Comment: Вот Это смутило в формулировке (при фиксированном настоящем будущее независимо от прошлого), а что если все же зависимо но зависимости не видно.Может уже есть в какой программе подобное. Или кому встречалоь

Comment: Смотря по какому закону перемешаны числа. Если по случайному, то в принципе никак нельзя предсказать (это и есть свойство случайных чисел).

Comment: Вероятнее всего последовательность не случайная, а псевдослучайная. Можно отталкиваться от этого.

Comment: дайте конкретный пример, и подлиннее )

Comment: Вы бы представили хотя бы минимальную выборку. Могу порекомендовать Е.С. Вентцель. Теория вероятностей

Comment: если _Ряд состоит исключительно из чисел 1, 2, 3 **в произвольном порядке**._ - любое следующее число будет правильным, так как порядок _произвольный_

Comment: Не согласен с Вашей правкой к моему ответу. Если период есть, то преобразование Фурье не нужно.

Comment: БПФ значительно ускоряет поиск закономерностей и дает понимание есть закономерности в заданной последовательности или нет. Хотя в некоторых случаях еще и Кепстральный анализ проводят

Comment: 1) БПФ - это быстрый адгоритм дискретного преобразования Фурье, и он существует не для любой длины выборки; 2) БПФ с гораздо большим успехом может быть использован для вычисления АКФ, хотя на способах вычисления АКФ я в ответе внимания не акцентировал; 3) в данном случае речь идёт о принципиальной возможности нахождения взимосвязей - а не о скорости их нахождения, когда они уже известны; 4) кепстральный анализ используется в основном для речевых сигналов.

Comment: Не согласен с Вами. БПФ можно использовать что бы понять есть там закономерности или нет. А зачем нам бесконечно большая выборка? Достаточно взять хотя бы 4096 отсчетов. Мне кажется это наиболее быстрое и простое решение. Я вот часто использую БПФ для анализа генераторов случайных чисел

Comment: Выборки пока нет вообще.

Comment: Что бы понять есть там закономерность или нет и не терять время

Comment: Alexsandr Ter скажите пожалуйста, а каким программным средством доступным в интернете можно это выполнить. Чем пользуетесь вы если не секрет.

Answer (score 6):

Можно пойти несколькими разными путями.

1. Найти период выборки, если он существует. Это можно сделать, вычисляя [автокорреляцию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Для ограниченных данных этот вариант перекрывает случаи авторегрессии и всякого рода управляющих сочетаний.
   Если возникает проблема быстродействия, то для вычисления АКФ можно использовать алгоритм быстрого дискретного преобразования Фурье (БПФ)
2. Расшифровать закон кодирования последовательности. Это может быть что угодно - к примеру, синусоида с соответствующим масштабированием и округлением.

Answer (score 5):

Смотря по какому закону перемешаны числа. Если по случайному, то в принципе никак нельзя предсказать (это и есть свойство случайных чисел).

Comment: Это если каждый результат независим от предыдущих и каждый имеет одинаковую вероятность (1/3 в данном случае). Необязательно это так.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Обычно случайные величины подчиняются [схеме Бернулли](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8): исход каждого следующего испытания никак не зависит от предыдущих. Так ведёт себя, например, честная монета или кубик, и, как я понимаю, именно это обычно называют случайной последовательностью. Автор вопроса, к сожалению, не указал, что за последовательность у него. В отсутствие других данных разумно предположить случайность.

Comment: @VladD да, я изучал тервер и матстатистику целый год в универе. =) `разумно предположить случайность` - ряд `1 2 1 2 1 2 (1 2)...` это тоже ведь случайные величины, просто они не подчиняются вышеупомянутой схеме и вероятность у них единичная.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Насколько я понимаю, конкретная последовательность не может быть случайной или неслучайной, случайной или неслучайной может быть лишь серия последовательностей. https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: @VladD я имею в виду конкретные величины. Мы берём монетку и многократно переворачиваем её на другую сторону. Каждый раз с вероятностью 1 если была решка, то станет орёл и наоборот. С вероятностью 0 мы перевернём, а там то же самое. ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Мне кажется, что элементы истинно случайной последовательности не должны зависеть друг от друга, но я уточню дома в 3-ей главе TAOCP.

Comment: Добрый вечер всем. Спасибо за огромное количество ответов, буду читать и знакомиться с методами. Вопрос еще и в том можно ли загнать последовательность например в матлаб или стаистику или реализовать в экселе. Выборка на сегодня составляет 1333 при этом, первые 75 не известны (опытным путем выяснил что они есть), а известны последующие 1258. 1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
  
3 1 1
1 3 1
1 1 3
3 3 1
1 3 3
3 1 3
  
3 2 2
2 3 2
2 2 3
3 3 2
2 3 3
3 2 3
  
2 1 1
1 2 1
1 1 2
2 2 1
1 2 2
2 1 2
  
1 3 2
1 2 3
2 3 1
2 1 3
3 1 2
3 2 1

Comment: Добрый вечер всем. Спасибо за огромное количество ответов, буду читать и знакомиться с методами. Вопрос еще и в том можно ли загнать последовательность в матлаб или стаистику или реализовать в экселе. Выборка на сегодня составляет 1333 при этом, первые 75 не известны (опытным путем выяснил что они есть может это тоже важно), а известны последующие 1258. Возможны следующие варианты их расположения тройками 111,222,333 
311,131,113,331,133,313,322,232,223,332,233,323,211,121,112,221,122,212,132,123,231,213,312,321 , то есть как бы 27 вариантов. К воскр перепишу всю выборку как пример и покажу ее